# Manipulating tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, arguments

Creating and using pl/sql proceedures which do not interact with data stored in a database are simple to make and execute, but of obvious limited use.

But I'm having some difficulty in manipulating such stored data.

For instance with the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_emp (emp_rec CONTACT%ROWTYPE) IS

  fistname VARCHAR (40);
  BEGIN
  firstname := TRIM(fname);
        UPDATE contact
        SET    FNAME = firstname
        WHERE CONTACT_ID = emp_rec.id;
   END update_emp;
   /
```

Which is designed to work on a CONTACT table which includes a column FNAME and primary key CONTACT_ID; the code above throws a compile error:

> identifier 'FNAME' must be declared

How do I get the function to know about this column?

Comment: You correctly use the parameter name to reference the ID column in your update statement. Why not try doing the same with the variable assignment?

Comment: what about this  `fistname VARCHAR (40);` and `firstname :=TRIM(fname);`  u missing `r` deceleration

Comment: "...of obvious limited use." Why? I would say quite the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
fistname := TRIM(fname);
```

you are referencing a *variable* `fname`, and that is not declared.

My guess is that you actually want to use the `fname` column from the record that is passed to the procedure:

```
fistname := TRIM(emp_rec.fname);
```

Comment: Just wondering: is the row an object passed by reference in that case?

Comment: @Duncan: you can picture it like that, yes. Although there are subtle differences between a "real" object type in Oracle and an "record type".

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance at you code it looks like the error is with the line

```
fistname := TRIM(fname);
```

The procedure doesn't know what fname is.

Answer (score 0):

You Declare `fistname VARCHAR (40);` and update statement you use `SET FNAME = firstname`

it should be a

`SET FNAME = fistname`

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need for the `firstname` variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_emp (emp_rec IN OUT CONTACT%ROWTYPE) IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE contact
    SET FNAME = TRIM(emp_rec.FNAME)
    WHERE CONTACT_ID = emp_rec.ID;
END update_emp;
```

Share and enjoy.